# Jmeter env custom function doesn't read environment variable

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I was following [blazemeter tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) on how to run **Jmeter** script from the command line (cmd.exe in Windows10 OS). I'm trying to pass environment variable to the Jmeter `${__env}` (according to [this page](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#envsupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup)) custom function, using Jmeter script from the command line. Below is the screenshot of the env function in Jmeter UI

[image: with quotes]

I've also tried without quotes `${__env(password)}` and also using **JSR223 PreProcessor**

```
vars.put("password",${__env(password)});
```

but that didn't work either.

Below is my command line

```
set password=MyPassword123
jmeter -n -t C:\Work\Jmeter\MyScript.jmx
```

But Jmeter fails to execute my test plan

```
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using C:\Work\Jmeter\MyScript.jmx
Starting the test @ Fri Sep 28 16:45:38 EDT 2018 (1538167538606)
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/Heapdump message on port 4445
summary =      2 in 00:00:01 =    3.1/s Avg:   250 Min:     1 Max:   499 Err:     1 (50.00%)
Tidying up ...    @ Fri Sep 28 16:45:39 EDT 2018 (1538167539431)
... end of run
```

Is it possible to read environment variable using Jmeter? How to properly set it up. Has anyone able to achieve this before? Thanks a lot people!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When you use [User Defined Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) remove the quotation marks around `"password"`, to wit:

   ```
   ${__env(password,,)
   ```
2. When you use [JSR223 Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) **don't inline the function into the script body**, either go for "Parameters" section or use code-based equivalent instead like:

   ```
   vars.put("password", System.getenv("password"))
   ```

   This is a form of "soft requirement" because [JMeter Functions and Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) syntax conflicts with [GString Templates](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/text/GStringTemplateEngine.html). Moreover it makes Groovy script compilation caching impossible negatively impacting the performance. Check out [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information regarding using Groovy scripting in JMeter tests

Demo:

[image: JMeter Env Function Groovy]

Comment: Thanks a lot Dmitri, I'll test it later and update with the results!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you installed the Custom Functions Plugin in JMeter Plugins Manager. `env` function is part of this plugin.

[image]